# SOLID Principles and Imports in Python

Tags: python, python-import, solid-principles

*I frequently have this problem.*

In my projects I have some user input that controls the flow of the code.

So let's say that the user will choose if the **Fruit** will be **banana** or **apple** and the code will do the right job.

I try to apply SOLID Principles in my code.

So I make a `Juicable` Interface for the fruits that will give me juice.

```py
    # fruits/juicable.py
    
    from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
    
    class Juicable(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def squeeze(self):
            pass
```

Now I make my fruit in a file called banana.py

```py
    # fruits/banana.py

    from fruits.juicable import Juicable

    class Banana(Juicable):
        def squeeze(self):
            print('Banana juice in the glass')
```

And I make another fruit in a file called apple.py

```py
    # fruits/apple.py

    from fruits.juicable import Juicable

    class Apple(Juicable):
        def squeeze(self):
            print('Apple juice in the glass')
```

Of course all fruits that make juice will implement the Juicable Interface.

In another file I want to make juice.

```py
    # bar/bartender.py
    
    from fruits.juicable import Juicable    

    def make_juice(fruit: Juicable):
        fruit.squeeze
```

## The problem

Based on user input, I usually import programmatically the correct Python module.

ex. `fruits/banana.py` if the user chooses **banana**, I make a `Banana()` and call `make_juice()` from the `bar/bartender.py`

### The first problem

is here because if I **build the program** as executable, there are no files... so it does not work.

To solve the problem I import all **Juicables** and just call the right one based on user's input.

But this breaks the **Dependency Inversion Principle**

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.

Right?

By adding

```py
    from fruits.banana import banana
    from fruits.apple import apple
```

To a higher level module, you need to update the module every time you add a new **Juicable**

Which also breaks the **Single Responsibility Principle**.

### The second problem

appears when I want to list all **Juicables** to the user to choose.

**First** I list all **juicables** with `os.listdir` because I know they are in the **fruits** directory. ( And it seems just wrong! )

**Then** there is the same problem with no1. If I make an executable, there are no files. So I need again to import every one of them from a Higher-level module. And call `__subclasses__()` from `Juicable` class to find all Juicables.

## The solution

In other languages you just call a similar `subclasses()` method and you are good to go but I don't know how imports work in other languages.

In Python. You need to **import** the file and load all `Juicables` first so later you can **call** a method to get you all subclasses *( all classes that implement the interface )*.

But I want to know what are my subclasses to import them.

**Is there a design flaw?**

**Where do I lose it?**

**Would it be better if somehow I import * **blindly**? And how is this done the right way?**

Comment: Design and development-practice questions as opposed to specific, narrow implementation questions belong on [programmers.se] rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said, this sounds like you're asking what a good-practice plugin framework in Python looks like, and that's not a wheel that requires reinvention -- there are good off-the-shelf options, some of them included in standard tools (f/e, `pkg_resources`). You might start with https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Import all the fruits in `fruits/__init__.py` and the user code then just imports this module `from . import fruits` and accesses everything via it `fruits.banana`. Then the calling code ever needs to update it's imports